# Converting a DAG to Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, networkx, gremlin, graph-algorithm

I am trying to convert a DAG to a binary tree. Consider the following graph
[image]

I want to have the following output for above tree.
[image]

Since A,B,C,E forms a diamond, to convert it into a tree, I need to move B and C into a line.

I have tried following:

1. Topological Sort : Output is A -> D -> B -> C -> E -> F .
2. Topological Sort with order : A -> [B,C,D] -> E -> F

Topological Path gives us a straight path. But, I want to preserve the sequence if possible i.e. A -> D.  However, if there is a diamond, I want a node to only have one parent and sequence these parents as well.

Is there a way to generate a tree from a DAG for above cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Algorithm in pseudo-code

```
 Run a topological sort on the graph

 For every node B, in reverse order of the topological sort:
    If B has more than one parent:
        Order its parents A1, A2, ..., An in the order of the topological sort
        For every i in 1..n-1:
            Add an arc from Ai to A(i+1)
            Remove the arc from Ai to B
```

### Proof of correctness

- The algorithm always terminates, since it is a loop of fixed length; its time complexity is `O(N^2)` where `N` is the number of nodes
- Immediately after the step on a given node B, B has no more than one parent
- If the step on a given node C has already been executed, then executing the step on a node B that comes before C in the topological order only adds arcs to nodes that come before C in the topological order; hence once a node's step has been executed, they never gain new parents.

This proves that the algorithm terminates and that every node has at most one parent after executing the algorithm. Since we only remove parents from nodes which had more than one parent, I think it also satisfies your question.

Comment: I will try to experiment with this algorithm and let you know.

Comment: This is working as expected. Is there a way to reduce complexity from `O(n^2)`. Best case I believe is going to be `O(n)`

Comment: The complexity is really O(N+M) where N is the number of vertices and M is the number of edges. I simplified to O(N^2) in my explanations; notice that M = O(N^2) and, if the graph is connected, then N = O(M).